# Week dates in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

First time posting. I have searched but can't get something that will work for exactly what I need.

We have a report and they want to see a breakdown per week of some figures. In SQL Server I would use this:

```
dateadd(WK,datediff(wk,0,Time_create-1),0)
```

So how would I do the equivalent for Oracle SQL?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you expand on "breakdown" ? You need to GROUP BY week or something else? Provide an example or more SQL code

Comment: That would have been helpful :).

What this report needs to do is the following:

select 

dateadd(WK,datediff(wk,0,c.Time_create-1),0) as "Date",
 
count(distinct c.Things) as "No of Things",  
 
 
 

 c.reg as "Reg Area" 
 
from table c
 
group by 

dateadd(WK,datediff(wk,0,c.Time_create-1),0),



c.reg;

I have added in the SQL server example of how it would be laid out. I can group  by month in Oracle but by week doesn't seem to have a way. 

I can see there is a way with week number, I guess I would then assign in a separate query the start date of that week?

Comment: @ThomasG thank you, I googled for ages this morning this is perfect. Much appreciated.